# 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead

Tags: swiftui

I have been using `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` in swiftUI, but it has been deprecated, and Xcode suggest to use statusBarManager property of the window scene instead.

Could someone give me an example of how to get the status bar height using statusBarManager property of the window scene?.

I have tried with:

```
let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

It appears to work on UiKit, but in my case, I am working with SwiftUI.

**NOTE**: I am **NOT** asking for "'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0".

I have been using UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height like:

```
VStack {
 ....
}
.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)
```

It works, but Xcode gives an alert.